# Simple mod_rewrite not working (pass two variables) cannot find answer

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I tried different online tools and tutorials about mod_rewrite but I cannot find what I am looking for.  I want to rewrite a URL like this (I won't include site domain since it is all within the same site directory):

```
/area-1/(random text here)/category-5/(random text here)/
```

I only want it to find the area number within the slashes (`/area-ID/`) and the category within the slashes (`/category-ID/`) and ignore all of the other text since it changes based on the page title.  I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^area-([-0-9]+)/([^/]*)/category-([-0-9]+)\/    test.php?id=$1&var=$2&cat_id=$3 [L]
```

The `$var=2` is empty and not needed, but needed to add something there to ignore the random stuff in the middle so that part can be removed.  The page actually loads without errors, but it doesn't pull up the category ID value.  Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it: delete the `\`:

```
RewriteRule ^area-([0-9-]+)/([^/]*)/category-([0-9-]+)/.*$    test.php?id=$1&var=$2&cat_id=$3 [L]
```

Also, you can simply ignore the middle part by doing the following, instead:

```
RewriteRule ^area-([0-9-]+)/[^/]*/category-([0-9-]+)/.*$    test.php?id=$1&cat_id=$2 [L]
```

In other words, just take out the parentheses, and it won't be matched as a group; it will just be ignored.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS BELOW:** The subdirectory is critical. The following complete .htaccess file works for me. You need to put it in the subdirectory (`directory` in your example in the comments below). In my example, it's `so`+`this question number` = `so20604099`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Change the lines below to match your real subdirectory name...
RewriteBase /so20604099/
RewriteRule ^location-([0-9-]+)/[^/]*/category-([0-9-]+)/.*$    test.php?id=$1&cat_id=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also have a file `/so20604099/test.php` containing the following:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
```

In this case, if I go to `http://myserver/so20604099/location-156/daytona-beach/category-53/foobar`, the output is:

```
array (size=2)
    'id' => string '156' (length=3)
    'cat_id' => string '53' (length=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if I test it and use $_GET['cat_id'] on the page it is an empty result?  I used your second code.  I did a print_r($_GET) and only got the id value: Array ( [id] => 156 )

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteBase` anywhere? If so, what is it? Also, is this .htaccess file in a subfolder? If so, which one?

Comment: Also, be sure to include `RewriteEngine On` above this rule.

Comment: RewriteEngine on is on.    I edited my reply after your comment, I mentioned that I printed the $_GET and it didnt locate the cat_id.  Not sure what RewriteBase is, need to look that up

Comment: OK no RewriteBase added, but I never needed it before?  Everything else works fine, just need to get two variables from the url instead of one.  It is in a subfolder during a test, but I noticed the other links work if there is a sub folder or not.

Comment: Hmm, I even changed the name of the cat_id variable just to make sure there wasn't a conflict and still no go.  Here is how the site url is displayed on the site:                                      http://www.site.com/directory/location-156/daytona-beach/category-53/bass-boats/  and I use mod rewrite: RewriteRule ^location-([0-9-]+)/[^/]*/category-([0-9-]+)/.*$   location.php?id=$1&cat_id=$2 [L] the real site uses location instead of area I just changed it for stackoverflow

Comment: That is critical information; the subdirectory makes all the difference in the world. Please see my reworked example above.

Comment: Haha ok it works kinda, I had another mod rewrite rule for when the cat_id wasnt used RewriteRule ^location-([-0-9]+)\/                               location.php?id=$1 [L] So how can I make it so that it uses that code you provided if a cat id exists and the code I just pasted when the cat_id doesnt exist?  Thanks!

Comment: Add this rule on a new line, immediately after the first one: `RewriteRule ^location-([0-9-]+)/.*$    location.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: Ah I got it!  Not sure if I did it correctly, but I moved my new code for when a cat_id doesn't exist BELOW the code you gave me, and it works.  I used:  RewriteRule ^location-([0-9-]+)/[^/]*/category-([0-9-]+)/.*$   location.php?id=$1&cat_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^location-([-0-9]+)/*                               location.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: Oh yes I will thanks a lot :)  I am new to this site, there is no way I could contact you for paid work?  Nothing big at all, just little things like this when I get stuck.  Thanks

Comment: No, sorry, but thanks for the kind words! Folks on here are friendly and glad to help with stuff like this.

Comment: OK thanks again.  I work 90 hours per week so sometimes I just need a quick solution instead of taking the time to explain what I am trying to do with code.  Thanks.